# Android Restrictions as Embedded OS

Tags: android, ip-restrictions

Someone recently told me that there was a licencing constraint that prevented Android from running on anything other than a tablet or mobile phone. I couldn't find any evidence for the constraint.  Does such a limitation exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there no such restrictions. You can run Android on whatever type of device you like.

Some applications you would expect to find in an Android device do have licensing restrictions, though. Android Market, GMail and GMaps to name a few.